# ROS websocker error. Unable to accept incoming connection. Reason: 'bson_only_mode'

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use `baxter_web`_interface package.

After launching `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` I am trying to establish connection over port 9090 using webpage,  it gives my those errors,

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1489421469.154949] Rosbridge WebSocket server started on port 9090
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1489421864.967072] Unable to accept incoming connection. Reason: 'bson_only_mode'
[INFO] [WallTime: 1489421864.967882] Client connected. 0 clients total.
```

Any ideas how to solve that problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256883/ros-websocker-error.-unable-to-accept-incoming-connection.-reason:-%27bson_only_mode%27/) by [raf4343](https://answers.ros.org/users/29192/raf4343/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out it was a package error. The bug is now fixed.

---

Originally posted by [raf4343](https://answers.ros.org/users/29192/raf4343/) with karma: 20 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-17**:
'package error' as in: in `rosbridge` or in `baxter_web`?

Could you perhaps provide a link to an issue that you reported?

**Comment by [raf4343](https://answers.ros.org/users/29192/raf4343/) on 2017-03-20**:
rosbridge_suite
https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/271